# set/use EventToCommand according to condition?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have an UserControl that is used to display 2 different kinds of ViewModels (both being basically a grid displaying data).

ViewModel A is for displaying some kind of data, AND on double click it does some action to edit that row.

ViewModel B is only used for displaying other data.

For ViewModel A, I need to have this simple EventToCommand from MVVM-Light

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="RowDoubleClick">
         <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditCommand}" />
      </i:EventTrigger>
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In the ViewModel B, I don't want to have that edit on RowDoubleClick, and even don't have the "EditCommand" property in the ViewModel.

So the question is, Can I have that EventToCommand applied according a bool WithDoubleClick property that is present in both ViewModels?

Answer (score 0):

You said that you're using MVVM Light, but in MVVM we generally use one view per view model, so you shouldn't really be doing what you're suggesting anyway. However, it *is* possible. Your program will still run if you have no `EditCommand` in your view model... you will just get an error in the `Output Window` in Visual Studio.

Comment: And if you don't like seeing exceptions in your Output Window, just add the EditCommand to the second view model, and set it to an empty method in your constructor like this:  EditCommand = new RelayCommand(() => { });  However, like @Sheridan was saying you may want to look for a way to follow a One View, One View Model pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I ended up with an empty "EditCommand".
I am using one View for various ViewModels because they are _almost_ the same, I have lots of screens for displaying grids of data, they differ in the columns in the grid and a couple things more that are configured by properties in each ViewModel